# HERE Maps SSL response from chrome

Tags: here-api

in Chrome I receive the following warning when accessing some of HERE's endpoints:

> The SSL certificate used to load resources from
>   https://signature.venue.maps.api.here.com will be distrusted in M70.
>   Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources.
>   See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.

Does HERE needs a new SSL certificate?

Answer (score 3):

The FAQ covers this:

> HERE is still using Symantec certificates on some endpoints. Did you know that Google Chrome will stop trusting those certificates? I'm getting warnings in my browser.
>
> Yes, we're aware that Google Chrome will stop supporting certificates
>   signed by Symantec with the M70 release, about October 23rd, as
>   announced on the Google Security Blog. We also monitor certificates
>   for all our endpoints in this regard. Affected certificates will be
>   replaced well before this date.

https://developer.here.com/faqs